# How do I find whether a string has a carriage return by using the String.Contain function using its ascii character?

Tags: c#, string, ascii, contains

In C#, how do I find whether a string has a carriage return by using the `String.Contains` function? 
The ascii for carriage return is 13.

`Chr(13)` is how a carriage return is represented in Visual Basic.  How is a carriage return represented in C# using its ascii character and not `"\r"`?

```
if (word.Contains(Chr(13))  
{  
    .  
    .  
    .  
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `"\r"` (or, if you want a `char`, `'\r'`)?

Answer (score 24):

```
if (word.Contains(Environment.NewLine)) { }
```

Comment: No, that's "\r\n" on Windows.

Comment: No, that's not the same. Environment.NewLine is usually (but not necessarily) a CRLF pair, i.e. char(13)+char(10).

Comment: That would be checking for OS specific NewLine in windows it's CRLF and on my mac it's LF

Comment: TBH I answered this way because I'm under the impression it's what the OP _should_ hear more than the answer he _wanted_ to hear. Either way he now has both answers :)

Answer (score 19):

Since you state that you don't want to use `\r` then you can cast the integer to a `char`:

```
if (word.Contains((char)13)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can enter a `char` value using single quotes

```
var s = "hello\r";

if (s.Contains('\r')) 
{

}
```

If it's easier to read, you can cast `13` to char

```
var s = "hello\r";

if (s.Contains((char)13)) 
{

}
```

Comment: It's even easier to read with: const char CR = '\r'; if(s.Contains(CR)) { ... }

Comment: @Olivier - yes, that's a bit easier on the eye :)

Answer (score 2):

This is valid in all .NET versions:

```
if (word.Contains("\r"))
{
  ...
}
```

This is valid only from .NET 3.5:

```
if (word.Contains('\r'))
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.Char(byte asciiValue)` creates a char from any integer; so

```
if (word.Contains(Convert.Char(13))
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
s.Contains('\x0D');
```

characters are represent using single quotes;

What's wrong with using \r ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can do this with a regular expression, but if you're dumb like me, this extension method is a good way to go:

```
public static bool HasLineBreaks(this string expression)
{
    return expression.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },StringSplitOptions.None).Length > 1;
}
```

Comment: Even though this works it's not optimal considering that it involves unnecessary string allocations. Having said that, for the sake of competeness I would also add the arcane "\f" (line feed) in the mix